# How do you make a subdomain after subdomain like sub1.sub2.example.com?

Tags: subdomain

I want to have a domain structure set up for development sites, such as project.dev.example.com. Can I do this easily in cpanel?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to do this in cpanel, it's probably one for webmasters.stackexchange.com - but if you want to do this in DNS it belongs here.

Comment: The answer depends on your provider. Some have DNS integrated into cpanel in an easy way to create subdomains, others have their own configuration methods, and others do not provide DNS at all. The answer (from us) is to contact your provider.

Comment: I'm open to both solutions, whether cPanel or just straight into DNS. DNS would be useful though. I'm running my own server so I guess I would have to do it myself Chris?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cpanel, go to the Subdomains page. In the field "Subdomain" enter "project.dev" - and make sure "example.com" is selected in the pulldown to the right. Set the Document Root as desired, or leave it as CPanel sets it. Et voila - there you have it.